# How can I move into a different job sector without burning bridges and without investing time in certifications I don't want nor need?

Tags: work-life-balance, stress

I was offered a job which I accepted. I don’t want to say too much, but it’s in an office. I was in an awful temp job getting treated quite badly, living with my parents The job gave me the opportunity to finally relocate and live with my boyfriend. It finally, after months of unemployment and uncertainty, gave me the opportunity to earn some money and be independent.

The catch is that my new boss wants me to study for a certain qualification, which would start in October. I really don’t want to do this. It will last up to three years and take up a lot of my personal time, time in which I want to study something else. I know it sounds bad, but this is not a sector I want to be in. I don’t like my job and my boss can be quite horrible. I really don’t want to have to spend years doing something I don’t value or want. It’s best I leave the space for someone else on the course.

I hope I don’t seem ungrateful, but I was desperate for work. If I had had other job offers, I would never have accepted.

What makes this worse is that I can’t start the course and leave half way through, as the company have offered to pay the fees, and if I leave during my studies I have to pay back a certain percentage, depending on when I go. I can do without that!

I applied for teacher training which is something I’ve wanted for ages and would be happy to put the work into (and I know it’s a lot of work). This would have started in September so I could get out on time, but was rejected. Now I have a few options:

- Resign in August, either with one’s weeks’ notice before 20th August (as I only owe 1 weeks’ notice when I’m on probation) or resign in early August anyway, as I will have to give 2 months’ notice out of probation. This avoids starting the course in October. This is okay, but I will need to find another job and am so scared I won’t or find one that’s as bad as the temp job I had!
- Ask my boss to delay starting the course to February. I’ve spoken to the provider and they are happy for me to defer until Feb even if I accept.. There is a chance my boss will say no or get annoyed with me. The plus is that I’ll have a year’s work on my CV if I leave in Feb, so it won’t look as ridiculous.

**How can I move into a different job sector without burning bridges and without investing time in certifications I don't want nor need?**

Comment: Hey Annie, welcome to the Workplace SE. I edited this a bit to put the focus on what I think your question is. As a Q&A site, we're not a forum for advice, so it's important the question is clear. Please feel free to build upon these edits to further clarify/put in your own words. Also, check out our [about] page, which gives new users a nice overview of how our site works. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

> How can I move into a different job sector without burning bridges and
>   without investing time in certifications I don't want nor need?

You don't want to do the work that appears to go along with this position. And delaying the certification work until February won't change that or the other factors that make you dislike the job, the sector, and your boss. It's unfortunate that you didn't know about the certification requirement during the interviewing process (or that you chose to ignore it?), but you have to live with the results now.

Given the way you have stated the problem, I don't see that you have expressed any viable option, other than finding a new job as quickly as possible, then giving your notice.

In order to avoid burning bridges, your best chance is to be nice in the way you handle your notice. Something along the lines of "I really appreciated the opportunity here, but I've come to realize that this job, and the required certifications that go along with it, aren't something I want to be doing at this point in my career."

In your new job search make sure you understand the nature of the job this time - including any study or certification work that might be required. You don't want to make too many false steps like this in your career, or it will become increasingly difficult to find the next job.